# Using .po keys in bottle i18n

Tags: python, templates, internationalization, gettext, bottle

In the [basic example for bottle i18n](https://github.com/iocast/bottle-i18n), the msgID is used to get the string in the corresponding language.

```
return bottle.template("<b>{{_('hello')}} I18N<b/>?")
```

in the [corresponding .po](https://github.com/iocast/bottle-i18n/blob/master/examples/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po), the msgid is defined:

```
msgid "hello"
msgstr "Hello"
```

In [other projects](https://github.com/crowdfavorite-mirrors/wp-wordpress-file-monitor/blob/74b51302fb6154495a098cab5d5a55dcf2e4208d/languages/wordpress-file-monitor.pot), the .po does not only contain msgid and msgstr, but also a key before, defined with a hash sign. This is especially useful for longer phrases to avoid clutter in source code:

```
#: wordpress_file_monitor.php:138 wordpress_file_monitor.php:147
msgid "Remove Alert"
msgstr "Benachrichtigung entfernen"
```

How can I access this # key using bottle-i18n?